# Creating databases in for loop, injecting iterator of loop to database name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to create four databases in for-loop. However, I got an error. Could you help me to resolve this problem ?

```
DO $$
    BEGIN
        FOR counter IN 1..2 LOOP
            CREATE DATABASE 'database_name_%', counter;
        END LOOP;
END; $$
```

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'Counter: %'"
> LINE 4:             CREATE DATABASE 'Counter: %', counter;
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation for the `CREATE DATABASE` command:

> CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed inside a transaction block.

And since:

> PostgreSQL actually treats every SQL statement as being executed within a transaction. If you do not issue a BEGIN command, then each individual statement has an implicit BEGIN and (if successful) COMMIT wrapped around it. A group of statements surrounded by BEGIN and COMMIT is sometimes called a transaction block

You can't create database in functions. So even if you can handle current problem, you won't be able to execute this function.